# Hiding Related List if there's no record

Tags: related-list, lightning-record-page

Does anyone knows some ways to hide a related list if there is no records? I tried to find in component visibility but it seems it's not possible. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a rollup field for the related object. Then, base your component visibility criteria on that rollup field.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).